# XML projet file - MSPDI - from Acess databse mbd

Tags: xml, database, ms-access, ms-project, mpxj

I'm looking for solutions to generate xml project-files (MSPDI) with data stored in a database (Acess database .mbd with the MsProject Database Format). Has anyone done this without mannually create the xml file?

My application used to work with MS Project 2003 but stop doing it with MSP 2007 and 2010. How it worked: I had data store in a oracle database and I used to use a MS project macro to open it or edit it. So first data was transfered to a Acess database mdb (who had the MsProject Database Format), then the mpd file was exported into Ms Project. similary to save the modifications done in Ms Project into the database.

Ms Project 2007 cant export .mdb files so the only way a can do it is with .xml files.

MPXJ is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to do away with the intermediate database/xml file and have your macro read/write to the Oracle DB directly?

Alternatively, if you want to avoid recoding, Steelray Project Exporter might give you the XML format you need, and I think it's free.

Comment: Fisrt, thanks for your answer! We thought about reading the poject data directly from the DB but we fear that it will be slower. The project data stored in the database might be quite big and I dont know if it is possible to request these data in 'backend'. I mean without a ms project visualisation of each filled champ at every request.   I will also take a look to Steelray Project Exporter